# C++ポインタと整数間の評価についてのエラー

Tags: c++

C言語系のポインタについての理解が浅すぎてこんなにも簡素なコードすら読めない私をお許し願います。ポインタの概念は理解しているつもりですが、つかいどころというのがどうにもわからなくて……

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char s[256];
    cin >> s;
    if (s[0] == "h") {
        cout << s << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

このプログラムが実行できないのはなぜか、正答例を踏まえてお教え願えませんでしょうか。
意とする動作は
＞入力受付
＞最初の文字が”h"ならばその文字列をそのまま返す
ただこれだけです。
このプログラム、ポインタの定義は一度もしていないのにも関わらず、エラーで「ポインタと整数の評価」を吐かれてしまうため、これ以上踏み込みようがなくて困っています。
どうかご回答よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

コードの中で

```
if (s[0] == "h") {
```

としていますが、これは`char`である`s[0]`と文字列の`"h"`を比べています。文字列は、実際には`const char`の配列で、配列はポインタとして使われるので、そのようなエラーになります。エラーメッセージでポインタは`"h"`を、整数は`s[0]`を指しています。

正しくは、文字列の代わりに文字を使います。

```
if (s[0] == 'h') { // シングルクォーテーションに替える
```

---

これで動くのですが、せっかくC++を使っているので、`std::string`を使う方がいいです。今のコードでは、256文字以上入力すると、クラッシュするなど変なことが起こります。

Comment: [C++20からはバッファサイズを見て書き込む](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2)ようになるので、質問文のコードでもクラッシュはしなくなりますね。